# Swift NSUserDefaults setObject for Array

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

i need to save with NSUserDefaults an array that i get from jSON, the problem is it save only the first string and not all the array. So if the array is like NewYork,London,Rome .. it save only NewYork. I use it for a picker view.
This is the code:

**EDIT** 
For save the Array from jSON:

```
   if let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: nil, error: &error) as? [String:AnyObject] { // dictionary
                if let locationsArray = jsonData["locations"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] { // array of dictionaries
                    for locationDictionary in locationsArray { // we loop in the array of dictionaries
                        if let location = locationDictionary["location_name"] as? String { // finally, access the dictionary like you were trying to do
                           // println(location)

                            var locationSave: Void = save.setObject(location, forKey: "Location")




                        }
                    }
                }
            }



        }
```

and for request the Array:

```
  var Location = save.objectForKey("Location")!

        var pickerviewFields = Location

   return pickerviewFields.count
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And where do you get `location` from in the first place?

Comment: is a variable with the array that i get from the database with json. If i print in the console the variable location i can see all locations without problem.. so is not var location the problem but is the "Location" variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can only save an NSArray, if the Array is a Swift Array, you will need to convert it.  Also, NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects.

Here's how you would convert the Array:

```
var MyArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
var MyNSArray: NSArray

MyNSArray = MyArray as NSArray

println("\(MyNSArray)")
```

Prints: (a,b,c)

I have a small example with some sample JSON:

```
    var myJSONString: NSString = "{ \"locations\" : [ { \"location_name\" : \"A\" }, { \"location_name\" : \"B\" }, { \"location_name\" : \"C\" }, { \"location_name\" : \"D\" } ] }"
    var urlData: NSData? = NSData()
    var error: NSError?
    var save = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    urlData = myJSONString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    if let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: nil, error: &error) as? NSDictionary { // dictionary
        if let locationsArray = jsonData["locations"] as? NSArray { // array of dictionaries
            for locationDictionary in locationsArray { // we loop in the array of dictionaries
                if let location = locationDictionary["location_name"] as? NSString { 
                    println(location)
                }
            }
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(locationsArray, forKey: "locationArray")
        }
    }

    println(save.dictionaryRepresentation())
```

Comment: I've added a small example to the answer on how to convert from Swift Array to NSArray. As for converting the whole result from JSON, I would suggest converting it to some kind of data object, I've used this library:  https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/JSONExport

Comment: it say: String is not convertible to NSArray

Comment: You have to convert the JSON result, first, something like this: jsonRes = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(returnData!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

Comment: Change this:  [String:AnyObject] to this:  NSDictionary

Comment: same problem, String is not convertible to NSArray

Comment: Can you show more of the code you are using, and the JSON string you want to save?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**Writing**

```
let locationArray = ["London", "NewYork", "Rome"]
let locationData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(locationArray)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(locationData, forKey: "Location")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

**Reading**

```
let locationData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Location") as? NSData
if let locationData = locationData {
    let locationArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(locationData) as? [String]

    if let locationArray = locationArray {
        println(locationArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is just a test

Comment: this is what it prints : [, ]
[, ]
[, ]
[, ]
[, ]
[, ]
[, ]
[, ]
[, ]
[, ]

Comment: check the EDIT i do.. i added the JSON code to get the array "location" thanks

Comment: Change this: `locationDictionary["location_name"] as? String` to this: `locationDictionary["location_name"] as? [String]`